# Command line audio player similar to mplayer in slave mode

Tags: linux, audio, command-line, mplayer

I'm looking for an audio player that can be controlled through the command line or STDIN.

I've been using Mplayer in Slave mode, but there are some bugs in how it calculates the duration of audio files that makes it unusable.

Any ideas? Ideally, I would like to be able to pass commands to the player through STDIN and be able to get back information from the player as to how its current position in an audio file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use MPD (http://mpd.wikia.com/wiki/Music_Player_Daemon_Wiki) with the MPC client.

For example:

```
% mpc status 
36 Crazyfists - At the End of August
[playing] #1/24   0:06/3:58 (2%)
volume: 79%   repeat: off   random: off   single: off   consume: off
```